# wget gives response ERROR: 418 unused

Tags: python, linux, http, wget

I am trying to run `wget http://about.me/xxxxxx`, which points to a personal page of about.me. Doing this gives me the response: ERROR 418 unused

I also tried to write a python script with urllib2 to download the same page but i get the same response.

Moreover, trying https instead of http redirects to http.

Of course if i normally try to browse the page with chrome, the page shows. Any idea why wget gives this weird http response?

How can i download the page i want?

Comment: `curl -s "http://about.me/<username>" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0` works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bunch of experiments, and it seems that they are looking for `Accept-Language` header.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener()
>>> r = urllib2.Request('http://about.me/<username>')
>>> r.add_header('Accept-Language', 'en')
>>> opener.open(r)
  > <addinfourl at 320988516504 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x4abc6073d0>>
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you find this by trial and error, or is there an easy way i can find out what headers does a website need?

Comment: @rob.z I just checked the headers that my browser sent (initially I was thinking about spoofing `User-Agent`, but turned out that's not the case), left the ones that seemed most relevant, and finally blindly guessed the one.